# Ipsí nihil per sé sine eó facere potuérunt

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation, wheelocks-latin

In the 2. sententiae antíquae exercise of the page 86 of Wheelock's Latin steht:

> Ipsí nihil per sé sine eó facere potuérunt.

My attempt to translate to my native Spanish goes

> Ellos mismos no han podido hacer nada por si mismos sin el.

Translating it to English:

> Themself have not been able to do anything by themself.

I am enigmatic about the apparent pleonasm of having both *Ipsí* and *per sé*.

Comment: "Themself have not been able" This isn't grammatical in English.

Comment: @cmw That is my English, very basic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, both translations might indeed be a bit pleonastic since both *ipsi* and *per se* are translated to very similar sets of words in both English and Spanish. However, *per se* and *ipse* have unambiguously distinct meanings in the original Latin sentence:

- **Ipsi**, which acts as a pronoun here, simply means *they* with an emphasis on the uniqueness of the group of people being mentioned.
- **Per se** means *by themselves*, *by their own effort*. It doesn't modify *they*, but the **action** that *they* are doing.

The two terms have nothing to do with each other, it's just that their translations happen to (almost) collide.

Appropriate translations of the sentence would go like this:

> Without him, they have not been able to do anything by themselves.

> Sin él, no pudieron hacer nada por sí mismos.

Notice how *ipsi* is translated to *they* / *ellos*, dropping the nuance that the Latin word carries in order to avoid repeating the *themselves* / *mismos* that came from translating *per se*. You could do otherwise and try to keep the original meaning intact:

> Without him, they themselves have not been able to do anything by themselves.

> Sin él, ellos mismos no pudieron hacer nada por sí mismos.

But this is ugly. I wouldn't expect this clumsy wording from any decent English/Spanish translation of a Latin book.